# c++ operator<< as parameter

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

Normally for overloading operator<< for a class in c++ I would do something like:

```
template <typename T>
void operator<< (const T &t)
{
    ostringstream stream;
    stream << t;
    // more code
}
```

I was wondering however either it would be possible to make the operator<< to be one of the parameters. One could create a method with `va_list` in order to format a string and pass additional parameters, for example:

```
void CBcLogger::print(MLL::ELogLevel lvl, const char* text, ...)
```

As you see in the above method I can pass the text to be formatted, as well as `lvl` parameter. If I wanted to use `operator<<`, would I be able to somehow squize more parameters than just the operator? Something like

```
void multiParamFunc(const unsigned int logLevel, "operator<< here")
```

I know this is not the right syntax and all but I am just trying to make a point.

I would appreciate all help regarding this case.
Also, I ask this in regard to pure c++ but in the end I would use it with QT. Maybe this framework gives some more functionalities?

Edit: I am making a logger framework. I need a function that would allow one to add a log line, which is described with its log lever (debug, info, error etc. Its an enum) and a "stream" that can be formatted with operator<< or va_args like in printf.

For example, the `print` call would look like this:

```
print(MLL::ERROR, "Some text to format %u %i %f", 1, -1, 3.14f);
```

As you see I can pass the log level parameter to this function. I am wondering how can I achieve simmilar functionality with operator<<.

Comment: This is a classical XY problem: you're asking how to implement a particular solution, but we have no idea **what** is the solution to? What problem are you trying to solve? **Why** do you care that `multiParamFunc` receives a method pointer (or a type factory, as it may be)? Please edit the question to start with the description of the general problem you're attempting to solve, and explain why you even think that passing operators around is a good idea. Also, C-style variadic functions are not type-safe and generally shouldn't be used. This is C++11 era, you don't need them!

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Is there a problem with just passing QStrings to your logger (which in theory it will need to convert them to anyway?) If there's no problem with that just use [`asprintf`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#asprintf)

Comment: I can do that but it doesnt look nice, i would have to do something like `print(MLL:ERROR, "the string %s", myQString.tostd().c_str())'. I dont mind additional conversion inside the function just want to write to the parameter as less as possible.

Comment: I still have no idea what you want to do. Forget about `operator<<`: after all, it's an implementation detail. **What are you trying to do?** Give an example that *doesn't* use `operator<<`, but still does what you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this exactly is what you want to do, but why not just have a simple class that contains a reference to the appropriate ostream?

```
class Message : public std::ostream{
  enum LogLevel { DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR };
  std::ostream* os;
public:
  static LogLevel threshold = DEBUG;
  Message(LogLevel level) : os(0){
    if(level > threshold){
      os = level > INFO ? &std::cerr : &std::cout;
    }
  }

  template<class T> std::ostream& operator<< (const T& t){ 
    return os ? (*os)<<t : this;
  }
};

Message(Message::DEBUG)<<"This won't be printed.\n";
Message(Message::INFO) <<"This will go to stdout.\n";
Message(Message::ERROR)<<"This will go to stderr.\n";
```

I don't think this will work as written but gives the basic idea.  To be a little more advanced, you can have the Message class own an ostringstream, which you can then also clone to a logfile in addition to cout/cerr, similar to [this](https://github.com/bloer/ConfigHandler/blob/master/include/Message.hh)

Comment: This is exacly what i meant. I will try to implement this. I only wonder how fast will this be if i have to create a new object for each message.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: Since the `Message` object does no allocations, it's bascially instant. By far the slowest part will be the stream's internal bits.

Comment: Ok, but your log level threshold is a constant. In my framework user has to set this level by calling a member of a class that contains the print method. Since I always create a new object, where can be the threshold stored? Would I have to somehow contain this message class in another one?

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of `QLoggingCategory` and associated streams?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: Threshold is static, but not constant.  So during processing command lines (or later) if you want more verbosity, you just do
    Message::threshold = Message::DEBUG